# Android App with External Display not working

Tags: java, android

I have an android app that launches one webview on the main screen and if it detects a second display, it will launch another webview.

```
package com.kwickpos.android;
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Presentation;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaRouter;
import android.media.MediaRouter.RouteInfo;
import android.media.MediaRouter.SimpleCallback;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  MediaRouter router=null;
  Presentation preso=null;
  SimpleCallback cb=null;
  private WebView wv;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    wv = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    //wv = findViewById(R.id.webView2);

    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
      }
    });
    wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
    // Check for the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission on Android 12
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S
            && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      // You may need to request this permission from the user
      requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW}, 1);
    }

  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
      if (cb==null) {
        cb=new RouteCallback();
        router=(MediaRouter)getSystemService(MEDIA_ROUTER_SERVICE);
      }

      handleRoute(router.getSelectedRoute(MediaRouter.ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO));
      router.addCallback(MediaRouter.ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO, cb);
    }
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
      clearPreso();

      if (router != null) {
        router.removeCallback(cb);
      }
    }
    //clear the cache and history *fixes bug where pole.php will launch at fresh install of app
    wv.clearCache(true);
    wv.clearHistory();
    super.onStop();
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
  private void handleRoute(RouteInfo route) {
    if (route == null) {
      clearPreso();
    }
    else {
      Display display=route.getPresentationDisplay();

      if (route.isEnabled() && display != null) {
        if (preso == null) {
          showPreso(route);
          Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "enabled route");
        }
        else if (preso.getDisplay().getDisplayId() != display.getDisplayId()) {
          clearPreso();
          showPreso(route);
          Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "switched route");
        }
        else {
          // no-op: should already be set
        }
      }
      else {
        clearPreso();
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "disabled route");
      }
    }
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
  private void clearPreso() {
    if (preso != null) {
      preso.dismiss();
      preso=null;
    }
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
  private void showPreso(RouteInfo route) {
    preso=new DifferentDisplay(this, route.getPresentationDisplay());
    //preso.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    preso.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SPLIT_TOUCH,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SPLIT_TOUCH);
    preso.show();
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
  private class RouteCallback extends SimpleCallback {
    @Override
    public void onRoutePresentationDisplayChanged(MediaRouter router,
                                                  RouteInfo route) {
      handleRoute(route);
    }
  }

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
  public class DifferentDisplay extends Presentation {
    public DifferentDisplay(Context ctxt, Display display) {
      super(ctxt, display);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.display1);
      WebView wv = findViewById(R.id.webView1);
      //wv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
      wv.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
      wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          view.loadUrl(url);
          return true;
        }
      });
      wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");

    }
  }
}
```

This code works fine when I run the APK on an android version 9, but when I run it on an android version 12 device, it loads both webviews, but will not allow me to interact with the screen at all. I am unable to exit our of the app as well. The only way to get out is to reboot the android computer. If I remove the second/external display for the android 12 version, it will work completely fine.